This usage of "would"

When you wouldn't come to my graduation, I tore you from my heart and buried you forever.

This is a simplified novel of Daddy-Long-Legs. Could you teach me this usage of "would". What is different from "When you didn't come to my gradiuation"?

If they wouldn't come to your graduation, they refused to come. They also didn't come.

When you didn't come... is a neutral statement about the fact that you were absent. It says nothing about reasons. Maybe you stayed away because you hate me. But maybe you were on the way to my graduation, only for your car to break down.
When you wouldn't come... adds a motive. It implies that you chose not to come; you refused to be there. You intentionally stayed away from my graduation.

This is a stylistic choice made by the author/writer to add poetic flair to an emotion. A very direct and unemotional way to write it would be "when you didn't come..." but then the second half of the sentence seems too melodramatic to make sense with "when you didn't come"
In "when you wouldn't come~", the writer is emphasizing Character A's rejection of Character B by deliberately not going to Character B's graduation. It wasn't accidental or "I forgot" but they chose not to go, thus making it a very intentional and calculated rejection of Character B.

Your sentence uses "would" in  A very direct and unemotional way to write it would be "when you didn't come...", how does "would" work in your sentence?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
